# MongoDB - aggregation - array of array data selection

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm want to create an aggregation for the following contents of a collection:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("574ffe9bda461e4b4b0043ab"), 
  "list1":  [
     "_id": "54",
     "list2": [
        {
          "lang": "EN",
          "value": "val1"
        },
        {
          "lang": "ES",
          "value": "val2"
        },
        {
          "lang": "FR",
          "value": "val3"
        },
        {
          "lang": "IT",
          "value": "val3"
        }
     ] 
  ]
}
```

From this collection i want to get as Object `("id": "54", "value": "val3")` the returned Object is based on condition : `list1.id = "54"` and `list2.lang = "IT"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple combination of [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to traverse your nested arrays:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$list1"
    },
    {
        $match: { "list1._id": "54" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$list1.list2"
    },
    {
        $match: { "list1.list2.lang": "IT" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$list1._id",
            val: "$list1.list2.value"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K5yuX8uG_BK).

If the `list._id` field is unique you can index it and swap first first two pipeline stages to filter out other documents before running `$unwind`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "list1._id": "54" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$list1"
    },        
    {
        $unwind: "$list1.list2"
    },
    {
        $match: { "list1.list2.lang": "IT" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$list1._id",
            val: "$list1.list2.value"
        }
    }
])
```